# layout_alignParentBottom in Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Can any one help me . I need a button at the bottom of the  screen. For relative layout layout i can use

android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

But what to use if i am using linear layout.
Please help

Comment: I don;t think so, can you take parent relativelayout so that you can add the button at the bottom of the screen

Comment: why do you insist on using LinearLayout. RelativeLayout is more flexible, right?

Comment: try using layout_gravity as bottom

Comment: can you past you layout file here?

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1.0">
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use (RelativeLayout) inside the (LinearLayout) and then add (android:layout_alignParentBottom="true") inside the (RelativeLayout).

Comment: How does putting a RelativeLayout inside a LinearLayout help you position a button at the bottom of the screen?
What happens if the LinearLayout did not math_parent on height property? also what is layout gravity now for? finally, you should subject a better solution like ConstraintLayout next time.